# Issue regarding printing of array elements in Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have an existing rails application. In one view file I want to print 2 array elements in a particular manner. My two arrays are @itemgroups_array and @all_brands_array,where @all_brands_array is an array of arrays. For each element of @itemgroups_array the corresponding element of @all_brands_array will be printed. As I just said each element of @all_brands_array is another array and since I want to print the innermost array elements in a same line,I have used join() method. Upto this its fine.

My code is:

```
<% counter = 0 %>
<% @itemgroups_array.each do |ig_name|%>
  <div id="<%=ig_name%>div">
    <%=ig_name%>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check_class" id="<%=ig_name%>c" checked="true">
    <%= @all_brands_array[counter].join(" ")%>

  </div>
  <% counter = counter + 1 %>
<%end%>
```

And it is giving output like this: (Conceptually)

```
Conveyor

Jeekay(AD) SKF

Bolt & Nut

Nirlon(AD) FAG SKF(AD)
```

where I have managed to print Nirlon(AD),FAG,SKF(AD) all in same line by the statement  @all_brands_array[counter].join(" "). But I want to print it as follows:

```
Conveyor   Jeekay(AD) SKF
Bolt & Nut   Nirlon(AD) FAG SKF(AD)
```

i.e conceptually outer array element and inner array elements in same line just like above line.

Please help me about this.

Thanks in advance!

My browser generated html for this section is:

```
<div id="persist">
        <div id="Conveyordiv">
            Conveyor
            <input type="checkbox" class="check_class" id="Conveyorc" checked="true">
            Jeekay(AD) SKF

        </div>
        <div id="Bolt &amp; Nutdiv">
            Bolt &amp; Nut
            <input type="checkbox" class="check_class" id="Bolt &amp; Nutc" checked="true">
            Nirlon(AD) FAG SKF(AD)

        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Where do 'Conveyor' and 'Bolt & Nut' come from? Which line is printing them?

Comment: Conveyor' and 'Bolt & Nut are coming from itemgroups_array. I am printing it through outer loop as ig_name by the statement <% itemgroups_array.each do |ig_name|%>

Comment: Can you check you html structure, if one item group and its brands are contained in one outer most div?

Comment: I can not get your point @JagdeepSingh

Comment: Is there any solution or its a weird thing? Just asking.

Comment: you can check the generated html in your browser

Comment: Can you show your array elements here?

Comment: Yes @SwapnilPatil  itemgroups_array is ["Conveyor", "Bolt & Nut"] and all_brands_array is [["Jeekey(AD)","SKF"],["Nirlon(AD)","FAG","SKF(AD)"]]

Comment: I think you are getting correct output what you want. The only thing is you want the elements in one line? Am i right?

Comment: Yes @SwapnilPatil,,,output is correct, I just want to print it in one line.

Comment: just try adding a `<span>` after `<%=ig_name%>` and close it before `</div>`

Comment: But later in javascript I need to catch all of its data including itemgroup name and brand name just from a single div innerHTML ,in this I can get this by document.getElementById("Conveyordiv").innerHTML. Will it work as it is if I use span ? @sa77

Comment: @Abhradip your code looks fine. I have tried it and I get this output (with no styling) - http://awesomescreenshot.com/0fd66t09ac
So the reason should be about some styles You have there. Get a firebug and try to play with it.

ALSO You do not need a `counter` variable there. Just `@itemgroups_array.each_with_index do |ig_name, index|` and then `@all_brands_array[index].join(" ")` will do the thing

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vla. Its working.

Answer (score 0):

Float left is the solution. Provide the div with enough width to the elements and put css property to the div as float:left.

try this:

```
<div id="persist">
    <div id="Conveyordiv">
      <div style='float:left'>
        Conveyor
      </div>
      <div style='float:left'>
        <input type="checkbox" class="check_class" id="Conveyorc" checked="true">
        Jeekay(AD) SKF
      </div>

    </div>
    <div id="Bolt &amp; Nutdiv">
      <div style='float:left'>
        Bolt &amp; Nut
      </div>
      <div style='float:left'>
        <input type="checkbox" class="check_class" id="Bolt &amp; Nutc" checked="true">
        Nirlon(AD) FAG SKF(AD)
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I dont need 2 inner div. That would cause problem in my case later.

Comment: You can handle it in javascript by providing id or class and can get the data. @Abhradip

Comment: You are not getting it. I have an existing webapp. I am working in production. So many things are dependent on each other. Cant change such way.